# Adding 'entries' field to a component's properties breaks the compiler

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm encountering a really weird bug in swagger.

When trying to render a component with a property called 'entries', the compiler breaks with the error:

```
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field.
Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that
match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).
```

An example that will return this error:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: API Documentation
  version: '1'
paths:
  /v1/detail/:
    get:
      tags:
        - clips
      summary: Get details
      operationId: Create Detail
      description: Retrieve details
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Clip'
          description: ''
components:
  schemas:
    Clip:
      type: object
      properties:
        entries:
          type: string
          example: 'abc'
```

But by renaming entries to something else, like 'x_entries', the compiler is OK.

I couldn't find any reference to 'entries' in the openapi documentation, although I could be wrong here. Does anyone know why 'entries' as an property in a component causes an issue?

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6016

Comment: Okay, thanks for the note. It's a bug then.

Answer (score 0):

It [was a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6016) in Swagger UI v. 3.25.3 and Swagger Editor v. 3.8.3.

Fixed in UI v. 3.25.4 and Editor v. 3.9.0.